# Complexity of building a certain-type of tree and traversing such tree?

Tags: complexity-theory

Given a set of k array :

**K = [k1 ,k2 ,k3 ,... ,kn]**

we want to build a tree such that its root node is k_m ,where m is the highest value in the list and its connected to every other node and again every node is connected to every other node : Ex-

This is a example of such tree made out of array of 4 arrays:
[image: This is such tree for a set of 4 array]

Another example of such tree for an array of 5 array:
[image]

I want to know what is the complexity of building such trees and also the complexity of travesing every nodes in such tree.

To clarify ,each node in this tree represent an array from the set of arrays given as input.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean by "m is the highest value in the list". For the mentioned examples could you please also show what were the inputs.

Comment: The inputs are given in this form A= [a ,b ,c ,d ,e] ,where a ,b ,c ,d ,e are arrays of length k ,where k is equal to the number of input arrays given ,and highest and lowest is decided based on the position at which they are placed in the array A ,here e is the highest and a is the lowest thus we can replace a ,b ,c ,d ,e with 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 and we'll get the tree mentioned above

Comment: its just an example where k=5

Comment: Please do not leave the explanation in comments else it would be difficult for the future visitors to follow. Please edit your question. And, use your notations properly; you have used the notation $k$ for different purposes. It is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$N_{m+1}=1+\sum_{i=1}^mN_i,\\N_1=1$$

so that by subtraction

$$N_{m+1}-N_m=N_m$$ which is obviously a geometric sequence,

$$N_m=2^{m-1}.$$

The creation and traversal time are both $O(2^m)$.

Comment: i don't really understand your argument ,can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: @Anuj: just count the nodes in your drawings.

Comment: yes ,that's what i wanted to clarify and prove